# fluid dynamics of two streams in single pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Background: The fetus needs to deliver both high and low oxygen tension blood within the same pipe (inferior vena cava) back to the right atrium. Blood entering the right atrium is able to cross an opening (foramen ovale) into the left atrium where it is then pumped into the systemic circulation by the left ventricle. Studies have made two observations:

1. highly oxygenated blood tends to selectively cross the foramen ovale into the left atrium while low oxygen tension blood remains within the right atrium
2. This highly oxygenated blood is in a separate stream from the low oxygen tension blood while traveling in the inferior  vena cava. It is this separation of blood into two separate streams based on oxygen tension that allows highly oxygenated blood to selectively enter the right atrium

I have a very basic understanding of fluid mechanics,but I have no idea how blood of different oxygen tensions could possibly be separated into two streams within the same pipe.

Questions:

1. Is it even possible to get two separate flow streams within one pipe? I suppose you could apply different pressures at the top of the pipe to certain parts of the fluid..but I have little understanding of how the dynamics would play out. Would such a setup even be stable?
2. If it is possible to do such a thing, I can't find any suggestions in the literature as to how streaming could selectively separate out blood of different oxygen tensions. I wonder whether viscocity differences could be a starting point..but I really don't know. Ideas are welcome.

Comment: As long as the flow is sufficiently laminar the two liquids will not mix strongly. Take a look at the video in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminar_flow. What happens in this system in particular is something that only a specialist on it can answer.